# Only allow some defined window sizes

Tags: java, swing, resize, window

I'm currently programming a Java App where I want to only allow some window sizes for the window. As Example I want that the user can resize the window (JFrame) to `200/300`, `350/400` and `400,450`. Now if the user resizes the window, it should be only accepted if the window matches the possible sizes.

It would be cool if the user could see in realtime if the window size is accepted or not. (eg: window size would stick at the possible sizes while resizing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy fix can be to disable manual resizing, and give a menu or something similar that gives the user a choice on the size of the window he wants, pretty much just like screen resolution in games..

Another solution which may be a little more complicated, is that you make an event on mouse release after the window has been resized, you check the new size and you 'round' it to the closest of your prefered sizes.

Comment: For me I think, the second option would be a bit simpler. But I'm going to use the `ComponentListener` and the `componentResized` method.

Answer (score 3):

[ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) can do that, but notice in case if you'll overlap maximum then `Container` would be flickering on the screen, but there exist code for [ComponentResizer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) code by @camickr

Answer (score 2):

This would really annoy me as an user.  I might temporarily want to use  a non standard size so that I could see things in your app plus another app, even if your app doesn't layout well at that size.

If you really have to limit the allowed sizes, then disable user resizing.  Then add a menu item where the user can select from the list of acceptable sizes.

Comment: Yes I understand. But in my case the sizes would just differ 5-7 pixels. The problem is that if I can't solve it like this, I'll have to rewrite much code to fix a layout problem.